# "Access denied" error in Google Webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors, 403-forbidden

I have an access denied problem in my webmaster tools. It says 404 errors.
How can I solve this? I have already fixed the errors, but they are not removed from Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 4):

Once Google Webmaster Tools reports 404 errors on your website, you have to fix the issue on the site, then you need to mark these errors as fixed in Google Webmaster Tools.

Then if this error appears again on your site, Google Webmaster Tools will report it again, otherwise it's fixed.